# How to get specific files using batch and findstr?

Tags: batch-file

I would like to get specific files from the directory:

```
> dir /B *.arj

bc170117.arj
be170117.arj
co170117.arj
curd0114.arj
curd0115.arj
curd0116.arj
ev_k0113.arj
kgrd0113.arj
kgrm1612.arj
metd0113.arj
rv503432.arj
test.arj
```

If I use

```
>dir /b *.arj | findstr /r "^k[a-z].*.arj$ ^c[a-z].*.arj$ ^ev_[a-z].*.arj$"
co170117.arj
curd0114.arj
curd0115.arj
curd0116.arj
ev_k0113.arj
kgrd0113.arj
kgrm1612.arj
```

It's ok.
But how can I match following files **[a-z][0-9].arj** and call function with matched result **[a-z]**? For example, output:

```
bc170117.arj bc
be170117.arj be
co170117.arj co
curd0114.arj curd
curd0115.arj curd
curd0116.arj curd
ev_k0113.arj ev_k
kgrd0113.arj kgrd
kgrm1612.arj kgrm
metd0113.arj metd
rv503432.arj rv
```

It's needs for calling function to do smth for every matched file.
This is one code doesn't work.

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %a IN ('dir /b *.arj | findstr /r "^[a-z][0-9].arj$"') DO ( call:myfunction [a-z] [a-z][0-9].arj )
```

**[a-z]** - match from the current file.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `call` is not able to handle REGEX. You probably want to use something like `call :myfunction %a`. Also you have to escape the pipe symbol inside your `for`: `^|`

Comment: Install **Ack** on window and this' it. [ack](http://beyondgrep.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you iterate over the list of files retrieved  with `dir` and filtered it by `findstr`, you only need to remove the numbers. Use another `for /f` with digits as delimiters to separate them from the initial characters

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    for /f "delims=" %%f in ('
        dir /b *.arj
        ^| findstr /r "^k ^c ^ev_"
    ') do for /f "delims=0123456789" %%a in ("%%~f") do (
        echo call :myFunction "%%~a" "%%~f" 
    )
```

This will simply echo to console the function call operation. Remove the `echo` command when the function is implemented.

Comment: Thanks! Your solution helps me. I've changed a little bit of code:              `for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /b *.arj ^| findstr /r [0-9]') do for /f "delims=0123456789" %%a in ("%%~f") do ( call :myfunc %%~a %%~f )`